# Github Project Page site custom domain with github pages

Tags: github-pages

I am thinking to create a blog in GitHub pages.

The location is below.

https://allanxu49.github.io/BlogTest/index.html

According to below article:
https://help.github.com/articles/custom-domain-redirects-for-github-pages-sites/

The URL must be **"BlogTest.CustomDomain.com"**

I prefer not to be limited to above URL.

Can I have domain "CustomDomain.com" or "www.CustomDomain.com" for my site above?

Before I but a DNS domain, I like to verify if I can choose the URL format that I like.

**Please note** that I am aware that I can probably get more flexibility with User Pages site. Bt I like to get this done with a *project page site*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Either with `ALIAS`, `ANAME` or `A` record to your DNS Provider : https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/